# QSqlrelationalTableModel.SubmitAll() returns an error

Tags: pyqt4, postgresql-9.4

I'm working on postgreSQL 9.5, QT4 and Python2.

I've brought data from a PostgreSQL query to a QTableView with this code :

```
self.nomtable = resultQuery
 if not self.nomtable:
    QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Alerte', u'Pas de données pour ce salarié et cette année')
 self.model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel(self, self.db)
 self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
 self.ui.tbv_suivtemp.setModel(self.model)
 self.ui.tbv_suivtemp.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.ui.tbv_suivtemp))
 self.ui.tbv_suivtemp.setSortingEnabled(True)
 self.model.setQuery(query_rempl_suivemp)
 self.model.select()
```

It works perfectly : data from the query is displayed in the QTableView.

But now, if an user modifies a number in a cell and push a button, I want new data to be entered in the model, to be then inserted in my database.

There's my piece of code to do that :

```
self.ui.btn_okannul.accepted.connect(self.sauvModifs)

def sauvModifs(self):
    self.model.submitAll()
    erreur = self.model.lastError().text()
    print erreur
```

Now, the error is :

```
ERROR:  syntax error on or near « = »
LIGNE 1 : PREPARE qpsqlpstmt_5 AS UPDATE  SET "juillet"=$1 WHERE "sp_i...
                                                       ^
(42601) QPSQL: Impossible to prepare the query
```

So, these are my questions :

- How could I have the whole error message?
- The error seams to occur in the submitAll() method, not in my code. How can I debug that?

Comment: There seems to be a few bugs with the `QPSQL` driver in Qt4 relating to prepared statements: see, for example, [QTBUG-48471](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48471) and [QTBUG-4431](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-4431). Since Qt4 is no longer supported or maintained (except for severe security bugs), I think you should test your code with PyQt5 to see if it still has the same problem.

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm programming a plugin for QGIS, which supports only QT4, as far as I know. I'll try to install QT5 somewhere to see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: But given the number of QGIS users and the constant use of QtableViews and models, I guess there must be a workaround fot QT4 (may be using a delegate or something like that)?

Comment: Maybe there aren't many people using the `QPSQL` driver? If you can't switch to PyQt5, you could try using one of the other [db backends that Qt4 supports](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#supported-databases). The problem with work-arounds for something like this is that it's hard to be sure that you've plugged all the holes. Do you really want to commit to relying on work-arounds for something that will never be properly fixed? If PostgreSQL continues to evolve, and the Qt4 driver doesn't, it's hard to see how the situation could ever improve.

Comment: PS: according to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/62548), it is already possible to use QGIS with Qt5.

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro. I saw in another discussion that the QSqlRelationalTableModel() class was really buggy. Using QSqlTableModel() instead solved the problem. It forced me to adapt my db table, cause I can't bring db data via a query anymore. But it works now perfectly.
However I'll try to compile QGIS with QT5, to begin to adapt my plugins to QGIS 3 , which will come out one day, with Python 3 and this version of  QT. Thanks for the tip!